# name "Clock is not defined" with Solver

Tags: python

I have encountered a similar error from 2 different projects (mainly fantasy Premier League projects)
When I get to the Solver part of the code, I keep getting Name Clock is not defined

[image]

Just in case the picture is not in the post

When I run this line

```
lp.writeLP('select_initial_team.lp')
sol = lp.solve()
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

      1 lp.writeLP('select_initial_team.lp')
----> 2 sol = lp.solve()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py in solve(self, solver, **kwargs)
   1668         wasNone, dummyVar = self.fixObjective()
   1669         #time it
-> 1670         self.solutionTime = -clock()
   1671         status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
   1672         self.solutionTime += clock()

NameError: name 'clock' is not defined
```

I cannot find anything about it and its a bit frustrating. If anyone can help, please do.

The library is the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pulp
```

Comment: This error is internal to pulp library, not necessarily with your code

Comment: You might report it to the pulp maintainers/devs and try to get an uptodate and stable version of the library.

Comment: What version of `pulp` are you using? Have you tried upgrading the version to see if that fixes the issue? (I ask because it appears that it should work on [the github  master](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/b99ff24891123fae928c6571d2eccd3e073eb385/pulp/pulp.py#L98))

Comment: Seems like this is related: https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues/244 but like was already said, you should tell us what versions of python and `pulp` you're using, and try updating to the latest version of `pulp` and see how that affects things.

Comment: My Pulp Version was 1.6.9, i have upgraded to the latest one (2.4) & I just tried it and I did not get the error. Thanks SuperStormer / Random Davis for suggesting the upgrade. Simple as that. Cheers Guys